# Objective C - Passing data between threads

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, variables

So I have a chunk of code that does some magic with a query and gives me a variable called `JSONresult` which has been told to run in it's own thread. Once I get this result, I would like take that variable from that thread and make it so that when an `IBAction` method is called on (triggerd by a button press) if data in the variable `JSONresult` exists that it will display it in an `NSTextView`.

So far I've been able to get the data to appear in an `NSTextView` if I specify the data manually within the `IBAction` method, but trying to use the `JSONresult` variable doesn't work for obvious reasons.

Here is what I've got so far.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getJSONquery) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

-(void)getJSONquery {
    [[NSThread currentThread] setName:@"Get JSON Query"];

    //Some fancy stuff here

    NSArray *JSONresult = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"<|...|>"];
}
```

After all this has happened and I've now got my `JSONresult` I have an `IBAction` setup so that if the button is pushed, the `JSONresult` will be taken and displayed in a `NSTextView`

```
-(IBAction)showContent:(id)sender {
    [content setString:JSONresult];
}
```

How would I go about passing the variable `JSONresult` between the two threads/methods?

Thanks in advance! :)

*Also if I should update this post with the header file please let me know. I'm new to the world of Objective C and have a very bad understanding of the general how-to so I don't know whether it's relevant to this situation or not*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data Between Threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646264/passing-data-between-threads)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really *pass* data between threads, as all threads have access to the same data within a process, however you need *synchronize* access to the data so that multiple threads don't trample over the shared data, which can lead to its corruption.

In your case, however I don't think their is much synchronization required so your question isn't about passing data between threads, it's more to do with how to make the JSON result available to the button method.

As has already been answered by @Leandros, you would normally do this using a private property:

YourClass.m:

```
@interface YourClass ()
@property NSArray *jsonResult;     // Note: strong, atomic
@end
```

...

```
-(void)getJSONquery {
    [[NSThread currentThread] setName:@"Get JSON Query"];

    //Some fancy stuff here

    self.jsonResult = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"<|...|>"];
}
```

Comment: Why do you use a atomic property? Does it really have to be thread safe?

Comment: @Leandros Yes, as multiple threads are using the property, however given the setter/getter is merely assigning a pointer it won't make much difference at all.

Comment: Sure, but since I can check if the pointer is set and only one thread is modifying it, I don't think it matters. But I agree, it isn't bad either.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a property.

```
// You can add this to the .h file.
@property (atomic, strong) NSArray *JSONresult;

// Or this above the @implementation in your .m file.
@interface YourClass()
@property (atomic, strong) NSArray *JSONresult;
@end

- (void)getJSONquery {
    [[NSThread currentThread] setName:@"Get JSON Query"];

    //Some fancy stuff here

    self.JSONresult = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"<|...|>"];
}

- (IBAction)showContent:(id)sender {
    if (self.JSONresult) {
        [content setString:self.JSONresult];
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this go in the .m or the .h file?

Comment: Yes, you can't set a `NSArray` as text to a `UILabel`.

Comment: When I press the button I get this in the console `2014-05-12 20:17:47.963 JaxWire[13454:303] *** -[NSTextView replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: nil NSString given.`

Comment: How would I go about converting it?

Comment: You can't really convert an array to a string, since an array holds a number of strings. You can add all strings in the array up, but this is another question.

Comment: If I were to specify a single key in the array, say `JSONresult[0]` would that work?

Comment: I tried doing within the `(IBOutlet)` method `NSLog(@"%@", self,JSONresult)` and it returns `(null`)

Comment: Well, than your `NSArray` isn't set yet.

Comment: Check if your property is named `JSONResult` or `JSONresult` (capital R).

Comment: Inside the `getJSONquery` method if I do `NSLog(@"%@", JSONresult)` it returns some data. It seems that the data isn't being passed between the methods

Comment: There must be an error on your side. Check your variable naming.

Comment: Since this about sharing values between threads I recommend using `atomic` instead of `nonatomic` for the property.

Comment: All the variable names seem to be in line. Perhaps would there be a better way to go about this rather than using separate methods? Essentially all I want is to just display the result into an `NSTextView` once it is generated.

Comment: Ahh. That's way easier to achieve. And something completely different.

Comment: @SteppingHat Refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489830/return-data-after-afnetworking-is-done/23489940#23489940

Comment: Awesome I'll have a look and see how I go. Thanks for all your help! :)